# How to determine the absolute path name of the compilation unit of the caller?

Tags: raku

According to [`p6doc 5to6-perlfunc`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/5to6-perlfunc#__FILE__):

> **FILE**
>
> Replaced by `$?FILE` which is slightly different from `__FILE__` in that
>   it is always *an absolute path*, rather than a relative one in the Perl
>   5 case.

and according to [`p6doc CallFrame`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/CallFrame):

> With no arguments the `callframe` will give you frame information for
>   the line calling `callframe`. The file and line annotations will be
>   identical to those in `$?FILE` and `$?LINE`.

But when I tested this, the `file` attribute gives a relative path name:

**./p.p6**:

```
use v6;
use Data::Dump::Tree;

use lib '.';
use MyModule;

say 'Main script: package path name     : ', $?FILE;
say 'Main script: $*PROGRAM-NAME        : ', $*PROGRAM-NAME;
MyModule::func();
```

**./MyModule.pm6**:

```
unit module MyModule;

our sub func() {
    say "func: This package path name     : ", $?FILE;
    my $frame = callframe 1;
    say "func: Calling package's file name: ", $frame.file;
}
```

**Output**:

```
Main script: package path name     : /home/hakon/test/perl6/./p.p6
Main script: $*PROGRAM-NAME        : ./p.p6
func: This package path name     : /home/hakon/test/perl6/MyModule.pm6 (MyModule)
func: Calling package's file name: ./p.p6
```

How can I get the absolute path name of the compilation unit of the caller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the [absolute method](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/absolute) from IO::Path?

`say "func: Calling package's file name: ", $frame.file.IO.absolute;`